Using viewport meta tags truncates keyframes animated text
I have a Python script that contacts the ChatGPT API and I'm using Flask to generate a webpage to write questions to ChatGPT and display the responses. I am using keyframes to animate the response, and am using viewport to better display the content in mobile browsers.
Using viewport means the text better fits the mobile browser but the animated text now gets truncated when it reaches the edge of the screen rather than wrapping; if I scroll across I cannot see any further text even though I know the text is incomplete. The relevant HTML is below.
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>ChatGPT project</title>
  <style>
    body {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: left;
      height: 100vh;
      flex-direction: column;
      font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
    }
    .container {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    }
    .image {
      margin-right: 20px;
    }
    .output {
      border: 0px solid #ddd;
      padding: 10px;
      display: inline-block;
      overflow: hidden;
      white-space: nowrap;
      animation: answer 4s linear 0s;
    }
    
    @keyframes answer {
        from {
        width: 0%;
        }
        to {
            width: 100%;
  }
  </style>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
</head>
<body>
  <p> Some blurb here...</p>
  <form method="POST">
    Your question: <input type="text" size="100px" name="user_input" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="submit" value="Ask">
  </form>
  {% if result %}
  <div class="container">
    <div class="output">{{ result }}</div>
  </div>
  {% endif %}
  {% if end_result %}
  <p>{{ end_result }}</p>
  {% endif %}
</body>
</html>

How can I get the animated text to wrap around rather than truncate? And, how can I speed up the animation on the mobile browser? (The speed is good on Chrome on MacOS, but sluggish on Chrome on Android).

This causes it overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;

@Paulie_D - amending/deleting those lines solves the wordwrap issue but then it dumps all the response on the screen and then you watch it spread out across the screen, whereas I want the text to appear letter by letter as it did previously.

Mentioning the <viewport> tag in the question makes no sense.
You need to animate not `width' but of the text itself.
Something like this:


const sourceStr =
  'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate, distinctio saepe ducimus expedita amet repudiandae nisi voluptas assumenda repellendus dolore.';
let destinationStr = '';
let currentIndex = 0;
const interval = 40;
let lastTimestamp = 0;

requestAnimationFrame(timestamp =>
  animateLetters(timestamp, animationComplete),
);

function animateLetters(timestamp, onComplete) {
  if (timestamp - lastTimestamp >= interval) {
    if (currentIndex < sourceStr.length) {
      destinationStr += sourceStr[currentIndex];
      currentIndex++;
      output.textContent = destinationStr;
      lastTimestamp = timestamp;
    }
  }

  if (currentIndex < sourceStr.length) {
    requestAnimationFrame(timestamp => animateLetters(timestamp, onComplete));
  } else {
    onComplete();
  }
}

function animationComplete() {
  console.log('end');
}
#output {
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 200px;
  border: solid 1px;
}
<div id="output"></div>



